# Change font-size in auto-generated HTML from px to em using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I have an `HTML` generated from a web service which I cannot control.  The `HTML` has font sizes in `px` and `pt`. My requirement is changing all font-sizes to `em`.

This is what I tried :

I tried to access all `<font>` tags using :

```
document.getElementByTagName('font').style.fontSize;
```

However, it is returning `null` even though I have many font tags in `HTML`.

All relevant sources I read assume we have control over `CSS` or `HTML` and hence do not apply to my problem.

In short, I want to parse the `HTML` and find all inline style (font-size) and change from any other type to `em`.

Comment: did you tried through css like this your parent Tag inside font tag...  #parent font{font-size:1em !important;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the styling is in HTML then it's inline styles. There's no CSS Wizardry that will override it. What you need to do is directly modify the inline styles.

Here's what you're looking for:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("elementID");
elem.setAttribute("style", "font-size: 2em");
```

You'll have problems in IE with `setAttribute` so if that's a concern ... you'll need to write a fallback to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementsByTagName`.......you are leaving out the s :)

Comment: ah. sorry, that that was what was throwing null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you are trying to change the style on an entire Node List.

When you call getElementsByTagName you do not get back a single element. You need to iterate over the elements in the node and then use `elememt.style.fontSize = size;` on each of the elements.

Here is a fiddle that implements that http://jsfiddle.net/Kfd2R/

Comment: Thanks...i got that bit and modified my code.It works fine now just like the fiddle you created. However is it advisable to use such px to em conversion? I was unsure and looking for alternate approach.

Comment: It is generally advisable to use either em or percent. You can run into some issues with setting size of font in px. A quite popular approach is to set a font size in the body of the document to 62.5% and then regulate the font size of specific elements using em.


An approach that you could try is stripping the inline styles and then injecting your own custom style sheet. That way you get to control all the styling on the page.